# What is the best practice for using services in Symfony instead of Controllers and not only there?

Tags: php, symfony

Well I'm learning Symfony (3.3) and I'm little confused about `Service Container`. In first tutorial the lector shows register, login, add post, edit, delete methods in User, Article Controllers. Then in other tutorial, they show same methods but using Service Container (User and Article services) with `User and Article interfaces`. So .. what is the best practice for **implementation in Services instead of Controllers.**

Comment: Not a down voter but by and large, stackoverflow is for questions with actual answers.  "Best practices" are not only a myth but are basically opinions.  There areas like Software Engineering which might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller** must implement the **application** logic like check if it's a post request or if a form is submit etc...
**Never** use DQL or any SQL Request directly inside a controller !

**EDIT** In the example i use a find method inside the controller because it's a **Repository** method but i parse the result inside `slugify` (my service method)

**Services** contains **business** logic like formatting phone numbers, parse some data etc...
Of course you can inject a repository inside a service and call your methods inside it.

An example:

```
//This is a fictive example
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
     //Application logic
     if(!$request->get('id')) {
         //redirect somewhere by example
     }
     $article  = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository(Article::class)
       ->find($request->get('id'));
     //Business Logic
     $slug = $this->get('my.acme.service')->slugify($article->getTitle());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: "Never use DQL or any SQL Request directly inside a controller !" << Why not ? What about Repository methods like `findAll(), findBy()` etc..

Comment: If you have to write some DQL, it has to be in **Repository** !
You can use find, findAll etc... inside a controller it's  **Repository**'s method.

**EDIT** BUT if you need to parse data from those methods it has to be inside a service like the example. Or directly call repository method inside a service is possible too !
The goal is to keep your controller simple.

Comment: I know that, about DQL always in Repository, but i mean from where to call these DQL methods, again Services, or depends on business/app logic ?

Comment: Thank u! Probably i will accept your answer, but i will wait for another answers. I also check example for inject repository in service container

Comment: The answer is to strict and suits not for all situations.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to Alexandre's answer that it is considered best practice to keep your controller 'thin'. In other words, only put code in your controller that really has to be there (or if it only makes sense to put it in your controller).

Services are like tools you can use in your application. A service in an object that helps you do something. In one service, you can have many functions. I think the best way to understand the difference is that a controller is for one specific action, a service can be used in many actions. So if you have parts of code that you want to use in more than one controller, create a service for it. And for the sake of re-usability, create functions in your service that do only *one* thing. This makes it easier along the way to use these functions.

Comment: With few words Controller - one specific action, Service methods again one specific action.

Comment: one of the goal of service is to respect [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) philosophy.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm, yes, but the service methods are actions that you can re-use over and over again in any controller.

Answer (score 1):

the "best practise" depends on what you want to do with the Service. If you build an REST-Api you might want to do Database-Operations in Controller. Why? When you rely on the SOLID-Pattern you want to reduce or eliminate redundant code. If you code a real REST Api you don't have redundant code because each REST-Verb will do a different query/thing.
So in a non-REST-Api-application  you will have a lot of redundant code. You do the same things/services on different pages/controller-actions. So the best thing is to implement all the business-logic in services to have it only one time in one place. If you have a lot of individual queries place them into repositories. If you have business-logic that fit's into an entity-class place them there. So in my opinion you can choose a thick controller/no service design in API's and a thin controller/thick service design in classic symfony front-/backend applications.
But one more thing: there is no totally wrong way to design an application. But if you work with other people or want to run the application longer than a month (without having trouble to maintain it) you should pick a common design-pattern.